# embed youtube video

Tags: html, youtube

In the html below, first object is using url of original video copied from browser address bar, second object is using url which is generated through youtube embed button.

why first object never works? is it something related to file extension?

```
 <object width="420" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3YcuiOWrSQ&feature=related"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3YcuiOWrSQ&feature=related" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
    </object>

   <object width="420" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/q3YcuiOWrSQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/q3YcuiOWrSQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
    </object>
```

thanks

Comment: First URL in first object isn't meant for embedding, it is meant for viewing on YouTube website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link doesn't actually return the flash file for the video. It returns a page that the video is embedded in. Youtube will use the `v` parameter in the query string to determine which video to load in the page.

The url for embedding made by youtube in the second object is generated as a direct link to the flash file.

The `Object` tag is expecting a link to a flash file and not a HTML page. Which is why the second url works.

Answer (score 0):

The URL from the address bar is to the full HTML page. The second URL is to the flash file which can be embedded. That's why the first one doesn't work and the second does. It needs the flash file to put in the `<object>`, not the HTML page.